# user_likes doesnt show it

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is my code:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                    array(
                                'scope' => 'user_likes,email',
                                'redirect_uri' =>  'https://apps.facebook.com/my-app',
                                'canvas'    => 1,
                                'fbconnect' => 1,
                                'req_perms' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_likes,read_stream'
                    )
);
```

I've a problem with user_likes, when I go to open the application for the first facebook doesn't recognize it, only email.

...and I need to detect if a user gave like.

Anyone know about it?

Answer (score 3):

As per v2.0 Facebook API changes, your application is no longer able to ask for permissions on anything besides `public_profile`, `email` and `user_friends` without first being reviewed by Facebook.

Please, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login for extended information about the Login Review process.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. Please update it to:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                    array(
                                'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,status_update,user_likes,read_stream',
                                'redirect_uri' =>  'https://apps.facebook.com/my-app',
                                'canvas'    => 1,
                                'fbconnect' => 1
                    )
);
```

There is no such thing as `req_perms`, everything comes under `scope`.